# Conditionally Load Different Modules on the Same Path in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a multiple user Angular app, with a module for each user (because they have totally different accessible pages), like this:

- app.module.ts
- app-routing.module.ts
- login/

  - login.component.ts
- admin/

  - pages/

    - user-management/
    - configuration/
  - admin.module.ts
  - admin-routing.module.ts
- user/

  - pages/

    - task-management/
    - configuration/
  - user.module.ts
  - user-routing.module.ts
- guest/

  - pages/
  - guest.module.ts
  - guest-routing.module.ts

From the login page (`/login` from app-routing), I want to redirect to each module based on the credentials the user provided, but **NOT** with children routes like `/user` `/admin` or `/guest`

Instead, when an admin logs in, I want the URL to be reset. So, for example, the admin should not see the paths `/admin/user-management` or `/admin/configuration`; it just accesses `/user-management` or `/configuration`

Is this possible? Will it be a problem if I have a `/configuration` route for both `admin` and `user`?

**EDIT:** Here's a [Stackblitz working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-routing-test). Take a look at the URL routes when logged in.

**EDIT 2:** In the Stackblitz example, you can see the original problem on `master` and the working solution on `solution` branches.

Comment: You have to go  and set up router guard ?

Comment: I have a `auth.guard.ts` implemented to restrict pages not accessible for users without the specific role, but the problem is with the URL route itself, not the access to it

Comment: If role is admin then you can use canLoad, canActivate, guard, to not load URL

Comment: Can you provide an example? I already use canActivate to let the admin only access the admin routes, but that's not the issue. The issue is, whenever I load a routed submodule (`UserModule`, `AdminModule`, `GuestModule`), I have to do it under a subroute (`/users` `/admin` `/guest` respectively). But I don't want that behavior. I want to load a submodule and use its routes under the root route (`/`)

Comment: Then put all this sub modules to parent path, it will load as a parent @GusSL

Comment: What is wrong with showing user, admin and guest?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof because it adds unnecessary length to the URL. A user with a role is not intended to be routed to the other user roles' pages. And as the submodule grows and the nested routes increase, it is annoying to see a `/admin` displayed prefixed to all the routes the admin will interact with.

Comment: Note that hiding URLs is not a secure solution. Other than aesthetics, this is not a useful feature.

Comment: Indeed, I also think this feature is more focused on URL aesthetics. Using guards complement the security part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

After a lot of investigation, I found out that it can be done with creating a route `matcher`.

**CODE:**

I managed to make it work with your code. Here is the working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-routing-test-qj4geu?file=src/app/user/user.component.html

This is the relevant code on `app-routing.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    matcher: url => {
      const user_type = localStorage.getItem('user_type');
      if (user_type === 'user') {
        return url.length ? { consumed: [] } : { consumed: url };
      }
      return null;
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  },
  {
    matcher: url => {
      const user_type = localStorage.getItem('user_type');
      if (user_type === 'admin') {
        return url.length ? { consumed: [] } : { consumed: url };
      }
      return null;
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    matcher: url => {
      const user_type = localStorage.getItem('user_type');
      if (user_type === 'guest') {
        return url.length ? { consumed: [] } : { consumed: url };
      }
      return null;
    },
    loadChildren: () => import('./guest/guest.module').then(m => m.GuestModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'login'
  }
];
```

**NOTE:**

As stated here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23866#issuecomment-388527483, when we use route `matcher` we need to specify which portion of the `url` was consumed by the `matcher` function, and the remaining portion will be send to the nested router.

**BLOGS:**

Here are two blog posts that has in-depth details and walk-through how to do it:

Blog 1: https://medium.com/@brandontroberts/custom-route-matching-with-the-angular-router-fbdd48665483

Blog 2: https://medium.com/@lenseg1/loading-different-angular-modules-or-components-on-routes-with-same-path-2bb9ba4b6566

Comment: The problem is that the module `admin` is loaded under the `/admin` route, and all the subroutes append `/admin`. Please take a look at the Stackblitz in the updated question.

Comment: The main routing works as intended! It seems that localStorage is the way to go, for not having to inject the global auth service. One thing though, the subroutes stopped working, even entering then manually in the URL. It seems it is not matching any of the subroutes when logged in and just jumps into the last one (`''`) in the submodules routing module.

Comment: After a few more hours of investigating, I solved that bug with a few lines of code. I updated the working example, and now all the sub-routes will work also. Can you check it?

Comment: It works nicely! However, I improved a little the solution to make it less repetitive, making the module selection in one single custom-matched route, but essentially it is the same as yours. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, I saw you suggested edit. Nice idea to put everything to one route `matcher`. But, the code you suggested didn't work when I tried it. It works first time when user logs in, but if you logout and log in again as the other user with different type, the module of previous user will be loaded. Check it here: https://www.loom.com/share/f9477b5c08b44652b1603c0a999d03ce

Comment: I updated the answer with current code in `app-routing.module.ts`. We can update it with one route `matcher` once we make it work for multiple logins by user with different types.

Comment: I just realized that and I kinda know why that happens. When logging in, a module is lazy-loaded, but when logging out and in again, the loaded module is still associated with the `/` route. While it seems one can destroy a module (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24962), a quick workaround is to reload the window when logging out to "unload" all sub-modules. I see it convenient, since it won't be very common to see users changing back and forth between accounts. You can see the updated `solution` branch here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-routing-test

Answer (score 2):

I gues your use lazy loading configuration looks something like this:

```js
  {
    path: 'config',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/userConfig/userConfig.module').then( m => m.UserConfigPageModule),
  },
```

You can convert the arrow function into a normal function and do e.g. an switch statement to deside what module you want to load:

```js
  {
    path: 'config',
    loadChildren: () => {
      switch(userType) {
        case 'IsAdmin':
          return import('./pages/adminConfig/adminConfig.module').then( m => m.AdminConfigPageModule);
        case 'IsUser':
          return import('./pages/userConfig/userConfig.module').then( m => m.UserConfigPageModule);
        default:
          return import('./pages/guestConfig/guestConfig.module').then( m => m.GuestConfigPageModule);
      }
    },
    canActivate: [ConfigGuard],
  },
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-routing-test-qxuewc?file=src/app/_core/services/auth.service.ts)

> Note:
> After logout you need to refresh the stackblitz view otherwise it kinda glitches. I'll look into it later.

Comment: This could be the solution. I use a BehaviorSubject in a global service to get the current user. How could I inject the service inside of the app-routing.module where I declare the routes? Also, please take a look at the Stackblitz, I updated the question.

Comment: @GusSL check out the stackblitz

Comment: It works, but when logged out and in again, it loads the last module. Anyway, the switch case idea helped a lot to build the final answer above. Thanks!