# Lazy loading Angular 13+ modules without the deprecated compiler

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I've worked extensively with [loading and instantiating Angular modules](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-module-wout-router?file=src/app/app.component.ts). (without the router)

But now with Angular 13 I'm seeing deprecations for the usual compiler tools to instantiate an NgModule:

[image]

Here is my usual go-to code for loading a module

```
const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module);
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
const componentFactory = moduleRef.instance.resolveComponent(selector);
```

Looking deeper
The V13 change where ViewContainerRef now has the factory included makes dynamic components 1 step easier. However, regarding [ViewContainerRef.createComponent()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent) the documentation states:

> Deprecated Angular no longer requires component factories to
> dynamically create components. Use different signature of the
> createComponent method, which allows passing Component class directly.

So what are the new directions for these tasks in Angular 13+?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can leverage a new [createNgModule](https://angular.io/api/core/createNgModule) method and replace these steps:

```
const moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(module);
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
```

with

```
const moduleRef = createNgModule(module, this.injector);
```

You can also read about all deprecations and possible replacement in Angular doc https://angular.io/guide/deprecations

Comment: Thanks @Yurzui! I think you helped me with a question when setting this up years ago too!

Comment: `createNgModuleRef` is deprecated too!

Comment: createNgModuleRef is deprecated as of 14.1, use createNgModule instead

Comment: this need to be used for ng 14.2.3 https://angular.io/api/core/createNgModule

Comment: "@angular/core" has no exported member named 'createNgModule'

Answer (score 3):

Here you go
Import the ViewContainerRef, Renderer2, Injector

Create a content element

```
const messageText = this.renderer.createText('message');
```

Create the component ref

```
const compRef = this.vcr.createComponent(<ComponentClass>, {Injector: this.injector, projectNodes: [[messageText]]});
```

If you want the element

```
const elem = compRef.location.nativeElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using the factory, you have to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`.
refer to the below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72174262/19077843