# How do you get the module of a component that's been dynamically loaded in Angular v13?

Tags: angular, angular13

In v12 you could use the following code to load/import a component dynamically, access its `NgModule` through `ComponentFactory` and then add it to the DOM using `ViewContainerRef`.

```
const injector: Injector = /* injected */
const cfg: ComponentFactoryResolver = /* injected */
const module = await import('path/to/component/file');
const componentDef = module['MyComponent'];
const cf: ComponentFactory = cfg.resolveComponentFactory(componentDef);
const compModule: NgModuleRef = (cf as any).ngModule;

const container: ViewContainerRef = /*retrieved using @ViewChild*/
container.createComponent(cf, null, injector, compModule)
```

As of v13 `ComponentFactory` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory)) and `ComponentFactoryResolver` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)) are now labeled as deprecated and a [new signature](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent) has been added to `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` which accepts a `componentType: Type<C>` as the first argument.

```
abstract createComponent<C>(componentType: Type<C>, options?: { index?: number; injector?: Injector; ngModuleRef?: NgModuleRef<unknown>; projectableNodes?: Node[][]; }): ComponentRef<C>
```

So you would now do the following to add a dynamically loaded component to the DOM.

```
const module = await import('path/to/component/file');
const componentDef = module['MyComponent'];

const container: ViewContainerRef = /*retrieved using @ViewChild*/
container.createComponent(componentDef)
```

However, the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createcomponent) for the new signature of `ViewContainerRef.createcomponent` show the 2nd optional argument is an object called `options` that has an optional property `ngModuleRef:NgModuleRef<unknown>`. For which the docs state:

> ngModuleRef: an NgModuleRef of the component's NgModule, you should almost always provide this to ensure that all expected providers are available for the component instantiation.

**Question**

I've struggled to find any example usage of `ViewContainerRef.createcomponent` that actually includes a value for `ngModuleRef` and with the deprecation of `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ComponentFactory` am wondering what the correct/official way to retrieve the module in which the component is declared?

**Edit**

Just to clarify, i'm interested in whether it's still possible to retrieve the module of a component that's been dynamically loaded using the new method in Angular v13, without explicitly knowing the type of that module?

Answer (score 7):

In Angular 13+, the solution is to create without using the DEPRECATED compiler.

without using the factory, you have to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`.

Import injector in constructor
 `constructor(private _injector: Injector) {}`
create module reference using `NgModuleRef(ngModule,parentInjector)`

```
const moduleRef: NgModuleRef<T> = createNgModuleRef(module, this._injector);
this.viewRef.createComponent(componentToOpen, {ngModuleRef: moduleRef});
```

You can also read about all deprecations and possible replacements in the Angular doc https://angular.io/guide/deprecations

**Edit 19.04.2023:**

Since `createNgModuleRef` is deprecated in Angular 13, you should use `createNgModule` instead:

```
const moduleRef: NgModuleRef<T> = createNgModule(module, this._injector);
this.viewRef.createComponent(componentToOpen, {ngModuleRef: moduleRef});
```

Comment: Thanks. In your example code where does `module` come from?

Comment: for `module`, you can import a separate `module.ts` or you can create a dynamic module
`@NgModule({`
      `imports: [],`
      `declarations: [],`
     `exports: [],`
    `})`
    `class ComponentModule { };`

`const module: Type<ComponentModule> = (<any>ComponentModule)`

Comment: Thanks Again. Sorry I think i might need to edit my question as it's actually better described by the title. Previously you could use `const cf: ComponentFactory = cfg.resolveComponentFactory(componentDef);
const compModule: NgModuleRef = (cf as any).ngModule;` to dynamically retrieve a components module. Therefore not having to explicitly know the module type. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this, as it appears that you now need to explicitly declare the module yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As i'm using single component angular modules ([SCAMs](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/emulating-tree-shakable-components-using-single-component-angular-modules-13do)) i also have access to the components module when the component file is loaded.

I'm using a naming convention of `MyComponent` whose module is named `MyComponentModule` so am able to access both the component Class and components NgModule Class using the component name. The NgModule Class can then be passed to `createNgModuleRef` to create the instance of `NgModuleRef` required for the `createComponent` method.

```
import {createNgModuleRef} from '@angular/core';

const injector: Injector = /* injected */
const compName = 'MyComponent';
const module = await import('path/to/component/file');
const componentClass = module[compName];
const ngModuleRef = createNgModuleRef(module[`${compName}Module`], injector);

const container: ViewContainerRef = /*retrieved using @ViewChild*/
container.createComponent(componentClass, {injector:injector, ngModuleRef:ngModuleRef})
```

However, this has the drawback of having to have direct access to the components module type, which is not ideal.