# Deprecated compiler module in Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

with Angular 13 I'm seeing deprecations for the usual compiler tools to instantiate an NgModule and Here is my usual go-to code for loading a module

```
    container: ViewContainerRef
    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(TemplateModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
        comp.componentType === TemplateComponent
    );
    const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
```

> Low-level service for running the angular compiler during runtime to create ComponentFactorys, which can later be used to create and render a Component instance.

> Each @NgModule provides an own Compiler to its injector, that will use the directives/pipes of the ng module for compilation of components.

> @publicApi

> @deprecated
> Ivy JIT mode doesn't require accessing this symbol. See JIT API changes due to ViewEngine deprecation for additional context.

Looking V13 change for above update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy loading Angular 13+ modules without the deprecated compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204754/lazy-loading-angular-13-modules-without-the-deprecated-compiler)

Comment: it doesnot as that one is just creating a module, here I am finding one then creating

Answer (score 0):

Without using the factory, you have to use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`.
refer to the below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72174262/19077843

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).