# Convert an Activated Route Snapshot to Activated Route -Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on the `canActivate` function of a guard in Angular 9. I want to navigate in the guard relative to a path. The problem is that I need to convert `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` to `ActivatedRoute`.

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot){
  if (allowRoute) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['route'], { relativeTo: next });
    //the error above is that relativeTo accepts a type of ActivatedRoute but next is ActivatedRouteSnapshot
    return false;
  }
}
```

What is the best way to fix this? Is there a direct way just to convert `next` to `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 relative route navigate in a guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995544/angular2-relative-route-navigate-in-a-guard)

Comment: @RafiHenig Thanks I have not seen that. It is close and gave me a few ideas. But I was hopping that it could be a little more general. Because route changes from a sibling to parent at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular team included `createUrlTreeFromSnapshot` function in one of the latest releases (14.*), :so now you can use `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` directly:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


    if (localStorage.getItem('payed_100000_usd')) {
      return true;
    }

    return createUrlTreeFromSnapshot(route, ['register']);
  }
```

Sample app: https://github.com/usarskyy/circulardependency/blob/master/src/app/auth/feature/auth-shell/guards/can-login.guard.ts